# Can I install the Graph Data Science (GDS) library embedded Neo4j in my Java applications?

Tags: java, neo4j

Can I install the Graph Data Science (GDS) library embedded Neo4j in my Java applications? My solution is that I want to include Neo4j with GDS library in a Java project as the standalone Neo4j Server. I do not want to use Neo4j desktop because I also need to develop some functions in the project. I have ever installed it by using Maven dependencies and call a graph algorithm via the browser but I got a problem. The problem is shown below:

`` There is no procedure with the name `gds.list` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed. ``

The steps of installation is exaplained as follows:

1. I add the dependencies to my project along the lines of the snippet below. This is usually done in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
<version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j.gds</groupId>
<artifactId>proc</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j.gds</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. I add syntaxs in neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*, gds.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*, gds.*
```

3. After a reboot, I try to show a list of currently active settings in neo4j.conf directly from Cypher on Neo4j Browser:

`CALL dbms.listConfig()`

**The value of "dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted" correctly shows on the browser.**

4. Then, I call it again by using the command below. I found an error.

`CALL gds.list()`

After I call that command, I got a problem that I have show above and below.

`` There is no procedure with the name `gds.list` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed. ``

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V203l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3AEQ.png)

Do I have to call a graph algorithm via Neo4j Java driver?
Anyone got an idea what I am missing here? I would really appreciate your help.